# Solr Search Query patten Change

Tags: indexing, solr

```
<fieldType name="text_gen_sort" class="solr.SortableTextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="true">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
<field name="label_en_US" type="text_gen_sort" docValues="true" multiValued="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

**Hi i have custom solr feild name  label_en_US which is  define as  text_gen_sort Type .My index is shown below**

```
**("LEMON FLAVOUR","NEW LEMON FLAVOUR","LEMON","LEMON FLAVOURS","FLAVOUR LEMON","FLAVOURS LEMON","NEW LEMON FLAVOURS","NEW FLAVOUR LEMON","NEW FLAVOURS LEMON",
"FLAVOUR LEMON NEW","FLAVOURS LEMON NEW","NEWF LAVOUR LEMON","NEWF LAVOUR LEMON")**
```

When I search

```
 serial:FLAVOUR^30
 serial:FLAVOUR*^20
 serial:*FLAVOUR^10
 serial:*FLAVOUR*^5
 label_en_US:FLAVOUR^30
 label_en_US:FLAVOUR*^20
 label_en_US:*FLAVOUR^15
 label_en_US:FLAVOUR*^10
 label_en_US:*FLAVOUR*^5
```

Query above result give from the solr But I need to change the order lable_en_US conatins key `FLAVOUR`  It must come firstly. Then `FLAVOUR *` and then `* FLAVOUR` and `* FLAVOUR *`  .

How can i achive this

1. It mean if some label contain extract match it should come first (currently happen )
2. After That if some label contain FLAVOUR string in the first part of the label like vise
   but current result

   {
   "id": "90547cd3e816cdcf81918a1094019ac2",
   "label_en_US": "LEMON FLAVOUR"
   },
   {
   "id": "90547cd3e816cdcf81918a109401b8e7",
   "label_en_US": "NEW LEMON FLAVOUR"
   },
   {
   "id": "90547cd3e816cdcf81918a1094019125",
   "label_en_US": "LEMON",
   },
   {
   "id": "90547cd3e816cdcf81918a109401a10d",
   "label_en_US": "LEMON FLAVOURS"
   },
   {
   "id": "90547cd3e816cdcf81918a109401ebe2",
   "**label_en_US": "FLAVOUR LEMON**"
   },
   {
   "id": "90547cd3e816cdcf81918a109401fb45",
   "label_en_US": "FLAVOURS LEMON"
   },
   {
   "id": "90547cd3e816cdcf81918a109401c0f6",
   "label_en_US": "NEW LEMON FLAVOURS"
   },
   {
   "id": "90547cd3e816cdcf81918a109401ced6",
   "label_en_US": "NEW FLAVOUR LEMON"
   },
   {
   "id": "90547cd3e816cdcf81918a109401dea0",
   "label_en_US": "NEW FLAVOURS LEMON"
   },
   {
   "id": "90547cd3e816cdcf81918a1094020f68",
   "label_en_US": "FLAVOUR LEMON NEW"
   },
   {
   "id": "90547cd3e816cdcf81918a1094021dc4",
   "label_en_US": "FLAVOURS LEMON NEW"
   },
   {
   "id": "90547cd3e816cdcf81918a10940224b1",
   "label_en_US": "NEWF LAVOUR LEMON"
   },
   {
   "id": "90547cd3e816cdcf81918a109404d4fa",
   "label_en_US": "NEWF LAVOUR LEMON"
   }

***But i need to get    "FLAVOUR LEMON" As first result***

Comment: did yor tries using dismax or edismax?

Comment: something like q=FLAVOUR&defType=edismax&qf=serial^15 label_en_US^5

Comment: if you want the exact match use string as type to your field

Comment: i have used edimax and need sort also

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti    q=FLAVOUR not working no

Comment: for sorting use the field which is of type string..